# Set custom permission on sharepoint list item using sandbox solution

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, sandbox

Looks like it's not possible to set custom permission on SharePoint list item using Sandbox solution, but thought to ask the question anyway.

I would like like to accomplish something like this in Sandbox solution: [List Item multiple users permissions programatically (sharepoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413374/list-item-multiple-users-permissions-programatically-sharepoint)

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Prem

Answer (score 0):

Basically it should be possible. The only thing unavailable for you would be `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, so you would have to check, if current user has enough permissions, to run `BreakRoleInheritance` and use for example `RoleAssignments`. Also, if you're thinking only about Sandbox solution (not SharePoint Online), you can move some of the functionality (like `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` to [Sandbox Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798427.aspx) in separate farm solution (these proxy are unavailable in Online version).